# Running my own written app doesn't show up in taskbar

Tags: c#, forms, silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have an app that is written using [Microsoft LightSwitch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff851953.aspx)
and i have another app which is using `Windows Forms`

when im calling the other app using this code

```
  if (Microsoft.LightSwitch.Runtime.Shell.Implementation.App.Current.HasElevatedPermissions)
            {
                using (dynamic cmd = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Shell.Application"))
                {
                    cmd.ShellExecute("X:\\Nima\\Application Files\\NimaLogin.exe", 1, true);
                }
            }
```

the other app (`NimaLogin.exe`) doesn't show up in the taskbar but i can see it at the process list

but when im running the other app manually from Visual Studio all is good and i can see the app itself

p.s i have tried `run` instead of `ShellExecute` but im getting an error

EDIT: this results that `NimaLogin.exe` "stuck" in the process list